# Deleting multiple rows from a table when out of disk space

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to delete about 5 million rows from a table that has about 6 million rows because I'm out of disk space. Is there a quick way to delete them? I've tried calling delete on batches, but it takes a very long time to run and sometimes it throws an error because of locks and doesn't do anything.

Edit:

I was doing a query that's something like

```
delete from <table> where updated_timestamp < '2012-02-20'
```

Now, to get smaller batches, the query is the following

```
delete from <table> where id < [100000 row increments]
```

The error I was getting was that it failed to get a lock on the table. I don't have the exact text at the moment, but if I run into it again, I'll paste it here

Answer (score 2):

The only way to delete rows is to either `DELETE FROM <table> WHERE <some condition>`, or delete all rows with either `TRUNCATE TABLE <table>` or `DROP TABLE <table>` (and then re-create it).

You've provided no information that can allow any more specific an answer than that, I'm afraid. You can do it in smaller sets of rows (batches) by using the condition in the `WHERE` clause. ("Sometimes throws an error" isn't useful in helping you to solve it, BTW, because "throws an error" is meaningless without information about what "an error" might be.)

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion in your situation is select the million records that you want to keep into a solid "temp" table, then truncate the table because when you delete the records it records all the records that you delete into the log which will take extra disk space. After you have truncate the table you add the records from the solid "temp" table back into the original table and drop the solid "temp" table.

Something else that you can do is to run a `CHECKPOINT` on the database, and then shrink it. It should free some space on the disk.

Answer (score 0):

The previous two answers are absolutely correct, and you should credit them for it.

What you're looking for is the following

```
SELECT * INTO into #temp FROM <table> WHERE updated_timestamp >= '2012-02-20'
TRUNCATE TABLE <table>
INSERT INTO <table> SELECT * FROM #temp
```

This becomes a little more complicated if you (a) have foreign keys referencing the table, or (b) have identity columns. For the former, you need to delete all records referencing records in the table via foreign key constraints, drop the constraint, then truncate and recreate the foreign keys. For the latter, you can use the following for the insert statement:

```
SET IDENTITY INSERT <table> ON
INSERT INTO <table> (<field_list>)
SELECT <field_list>) FROM #temp
SET IDENTITY INSERT <table> ON
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is code for deleting log table, where log is older than one year. with batch loop.

```
declare @batch int
declare @i int
declare @j int 
set @batch = 1000 
set @j = (select (COUNT(*)/@batch) + 1  from LOG_TABLE 
                where ACCESS_DATE <  dateadd(year,-1,getdate()))
set @i = 0
print @j

while (@i < @j)
BEGIN



delete top (@batch)
from LOG_TABLE 
where ACCESS_DATE < dateadd(year,-1,getdate())
SET @i = @i + 1
END
```